# How long an extension ladder do I need?

Tags: ladder

I'm planning to do some projects around my house.  One is to change a light at the exterior peak of my garage, which is about 28' tall.  The other is some painting on the side of my house, which is about 18' tall.  I looked at a [chart](https://www.wernerco.com/us/support/how-to-choose-a-ladder/ladder-height) from a ladder maker and it looks like I could use a 28 or 32 foot extension ladder.  Does that sound right and would either work for both jobs?

Comment: I've got a 24' extension ladder. I'm not afraid of heights, but I _hate_ using that sucker at full extension. It's very wobbly and disconcerting. At a minimum, if you're buying a ladder that long, be sure to get a stabilizer that attaches to the top of the ladder and makes a wider base at the top. That will help a bit. Also, if you're buying aluminum, be sure to watch out for power lines - you don't want extending your ladder to be the last thing you ever do!

Comment: While the 28' might do, a 32' will leave more overlap between the base and the fly, and that will provide a bit more stiffness. That will lead to you _feeling_ more secure (I doubt it will actually be any more secure), and that will make it more comfortable for you to work from it. TBH, I'd _strongly_ recommend renting scaffold for working at those heights, especially painting where you need side-to-side movement. It's a lot of up 'n down to paint from a ladder because you can't _safely_ reach much from a ladder.

Comment: I use pump jacks, a Jack system that connects to a pair of 4x4’s then you lay the scaffold planking between them but you still need a ladder to climb up once you are in the air. Left as a comment because this would not be for the light but if hand painting or doing exterior siding work they are better than a ladder. I would only get the steel ones mine have lasted for decades.

Comment: Excellent idea, @EdBeal, and thanks for the reminder and the proper search term. I'm considering these for the siding work I'll be doing on my house this summer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not stepping off the ladder then either will be fine. If you are stepping off to a roof you want the ladder to be taller than the roof line.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. This site prefers answers that use words to explain how to do something. Once you have written and good answer it may be helpful to  add a link that supports the detailed answer you are providing. Please take the tour so you know how to participate here. https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour - https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer